# Conditional select statement using 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a conditional case statement and am not sure if sql can perform this. 
I need to select the ID from Table A, and the Name from the corresponding ID in table B. If the Name in Table B is NULL, i need to select the Name from Table C. I am not sure how to do this using a CASE or if it is possible, any help is greatly appriciated.

```
Table A      Table B         Table C       
ID   ID2     ID2    Name      ID2    Name    
________     ___________      ___________   
1     3      1      bill      1     NULL        
2     2      2      steve     2     NULL
3     1      3       NULL     3     george
```

Comment: are you usin PHP ?

Comment: Just MYSQL, Also using talend for an import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IFNULL()` to select the appropriate column from `B` or `C`.

```
SELECT a.id, IFNULL(b.name, c.name) AS name
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.id = b.id2
JOIN c ON a.id = c.id2
```

If the matching rows could be missing from `B` or `C`, use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
select IFNULL(TableB.name, TableC.name) as name 
from TableA 
left join TableB TableA.ID2=TableB.ID2 
left join TableC TableA.ID2=TableC.ID2
```

Comment: why use left join instead of inner join or other?

Comment: @I'mBlueDaBaDee If row doesn't exist in TableB or TableC inner join will lead to empty result set.

Comment: that was a test! : )

Answer (score 0):

I was too slow :p
Here is a fiddle, if it might help someone: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b28c5/2

I assumed that each ID2 value is present in either both or none of TableB/TableC.